# Display Table Dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

this might be a dumb question, But I think if I ask, I could be find my solution. I have to display a table daily. Every days' tables must be stored in database or something. Users can go through calendar and see the tables. The main problem is how can I save these tables? The structure of table changes everyday. Some day, there are 2 tables, some day 3.

I've got these ways to do this :

-- Everyday I draw tables in html and the values, save it to database manually. (which is really I don't want to. I'm doing it that way now. )

-- Create table drawer in my admin page, and save it to database. (which is really hard to do this. i think.)

-- Save these tables to excel (.xls) files and save the path to the database. (which is if is it possible, that'd be great!)

Any suggestions?

BTW, I'm using ASP.Net and C# for my code behind. The database system is MSSql.

Answer (score 0):

I want to konw where your table‘s data come from ? what your method just is save static infomation into database,meanwhile this is the problem of your application modified everyday. if the data in the tables(table of html) can diviede into diffrent table( table of database ) and persist into database， then you can dynamically organize and display tables(table of html) with different table’s ( table of database ) data . I hope what i  say can help you .

Comment: Everyday, I receive excel files. And I display it to the website.

Comment: If I could display excel table in plain html, that would be awesome. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: If the data in exels is no regulations everayday, I will  save the path in database then display it in plain html as you said.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is read the excel file in DataTable and then display it in grid or something, you can use below to load excel in Datatable.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
...
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from MyObject", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```